# Manually dispose OWIN WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm trying to use OWIN to Self-Host Web API while running my tests and I want to start it in `BeforeEach` and stop in `AfterEach` methods.

All examples, that I found suggests to use `using` keyword, e.g.

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)) 
{ 
   ...
}
```

But in my case it doesn't help.

I tried to do like this:

```
private IDisposable _webApp;

public override void BeforeEach()
{
    _webApp = WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>("http://localhost:99999/");
}

public override void AfterEach()
{
    base.AfterEach();

    if (_webApp != null)
        _webApp.Dispose();
}
```

But for some reason it calls `Dispose` method of `UnityResolver` class and then I get `stackoverflow...` exception.

**How should I properly dispose OWIN host?**

Comment: What do you mean by "in my case it didn't help"?

Comment: @DavidL I mean, that it won't work if I put `using` block in `BeforeEach` method. I guess, that before running each test it will start the host and immediately stop it. And I want to stop it in `AfterEach` method.

Comment: Could you post code of `OwinStartup` class? Problem might be in there, since your implementation looks OK.

Comment: @drax i'm experiencing a similar issue. Do you what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @drax already stated in the comments - my dispose implementation is **correct**.

The problem was with my inner implementation in UnityResolver class, which was initiated in `OwinStartup` class.

However I faced some other limitations related to OAuth Authorization Server with Owin, so I decided not to overcomplicate my code and ditch Owin stuff. At least for now.

Comment: What do you mean by the UnityResolver inner implementation? I'm having a similar issue that is why i'm asking.

Comment: @programmingheadaches Well my UnityResolver class had `Dispose` method with some logic inside and this method was called instead of my owin dispose implementation.